# PieChart (HighCharts) Data and Labels

Tags: highcharts, django-views

I am rendering a pie-chart from Highcharts in Django.
The idea here is to render the chart using an asynchronous call, returning a JsonResponse from the server.

However, while I can pass the values into the pie-chart, I struggle to understand how to format the data to pass the values and the value name

The data used for the chart comes from an SQL query (Django ORM).

```
def highchart_two(request):
    return render(request, 'logg_in_app/highchart2.html')

def highchart_chart_data(request):
    context_data = MaterialPlantVendor.objects \
    .filter(plant_code='A1') \
    .annotate(total=Count('material_name')) \
    .order_by('-spend_2015')
```

I am able to create the Chart by using the following code:
Basically passing the list (ml) directly into the Chart Data

```
ml=[]
for item in context_data:
    ispen=int(item.spend_2015)
    ml.append(ispen)

chart = {
        'chart': {'type': 'pie'},
        'title': {'text': pn},
        'tooltip': {
           'pointFormat': '<b>{point.name}</b>: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                    },
        'series': [{
            'innerSize': '65%',
            'data': ml,
                }]
        }

return JsonResponse(chart)
```

However, I cannot figure out how to also pass the Value names.
According to the examples you should be able to pass the data in the following format:

```
data: [
              ['Firefox',   45.0],
              ['IE',       26.8],
              ['Chrome',   12.8],
              ['Safari',    8.5],
              ['Opera',     6.2],
              ['Others',   0.7]
```

I have tried zip lists but that did not work...
I am sure there must be straight forward method of achieving this.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data in this format, however, you have to define `series.keys` an array specifying which option maps to which key in the data point array:

```
series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    keys: ['name', 'y', 'sliced', 'selected'],
    data: [
        ['Firefox', 45.0],
        ['IE', 26.8],
        ['Chrome', 12.8, true, true],
        ['Safari', 8.5],
        ['Opera', 6.2],
        ['Others', 0.7]
    ]
}]
```

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.keys

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/us8qrjxy/

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer and the structure for passing the data:
    def highchart_two(request):
        return render(request, 'logg_in_app/highchart2.html')

```
def highchart_chart_data(request):
    context_data = MaterialPlantVendor.objects \
    .filter(plant_code='A1') \
    .annotate(total=Count('material_name')) \
    .order_by('-spend_2015')

ml=[]
for item in context_data:
    ispen=int(item.spend_2015)
    ml.append(ispen)


ValNa=[]
for item in context_data:
    strval = str(item.material_name)
    ValNa.append(strval)
```

And here the critical part:

```
list_num_chars = [{'name':a, 'y':b} for a,b in zip(ValNa, ml)]


chart = {
        'chart': {'type': 'pie'},
        'title': {'text': pn},
        'tooltip': {
           'pointFormat': '<b>{point.name}</b>: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                    },
        'series': [{
            'innerSize': '65%',
            'data': list_num_chars,
                }]
        }
return JsonResponse(chart)
```